# error 'value of type Realm.Configuration' has no member path', swift 2.2

Tags: swift2, realm

I have a red alert error  'value of type 'Realm.Configuration 'has no member 'path'.

I have not yet run the project as I'm building it, copying files and settings exactly from another project which has realm running fine.
Any ideas?

The error is on the line 
        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)

it is on my MapViewController (a long swift file with a lot of code so I'm not sure which part to copy here. The top of the file has 'import RealmSwift', which is in my pod file.

the code block is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    title = "Map"

    locationManager.delegate = self

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)
    populateMap()


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Realm.Configuration.path` property was changed from a `String?` to a `fileURL: NSURL?` property in Realm 0.99.0. It's likely that you're using a more recent version of Realm than that, which removed the `path` property.

So change `path` to `fileURL`.

Comment: I can't tell you how much you helped just now. After so much torture over this, I was at a loss- and this was really getting me down. Thank you @jpsim. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
```